# Gallery Image (flexslider) like apple.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am a web developer and i'm trying to develop a flex slider like apple.com
Can someone help me?

[Apple FlexSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkIwh.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Post what you have tried. Or search the internet, you will get a lot.

Comment: ok thanks :-) @JohnConde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this plugin: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ You must make just small adjustments for css, and is easy to work with...